# Extjs 4 combo xml store load?

Tags: extjs

I am using ext-4.2.1, below is the code. It has two problems, (1) buildCategoryStore(), combo can't find the store. (2) the below is the xml data, looks like the store xml reader doesn't work, how to set up the xml root ?

Thanks

```
Ext.define('App.view.QuestionForm',{
    extend      : 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias       : 'widget.QuestionForm',
    requires    : [],  

    initComponent   : function(){
        var me = this;

        me.items = me.buildItems();       
        me.callParent();
    },

    buildCategoryStore: function(){
        var CategoryStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            autoLoad: true,
            fields: ['id','name'],
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'rs/question/getAllCategories',
                reader: {
                    type:'xml',
                    root: 'CategoryList'
                }
            },
            storeId: 'CategoryStore',
            root: 'CategoryList'
        });
        return CategoryStore;
    },  
    buildItems : function(){
        return [
        {
            xtype: 'combo',
            anchor: '100%',
            fieldLabel  : 'Category',
            store: buildCategoryStore(),
            name: 'category',           
            mode: 'local',
            multiSelect: false
        },

        ];
    },

    }

});
```

xml data :

```
<CategoryList>

<Category>
<active>Y</active>
<id>1000</id>
<name>Life</name>
<versionNum>0</versionNum>
</Category>

<Category>
<active>Y</active>
<id>1001</id>
<name>Career</name>
<versionNum>0</versionNum>
</Category>
</CategoryList>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed up your code. The important parts are you need to call `this.foo()` and you need to specify the record param for the reader.

```
Ext.define('App.view.QuestionForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.QuestionForm',

    requires: [
        'Ext.data.Store'
    ],

    initComponent: function() {
        this.items = this.buildItems();
        this.callParent();
    },

    buildCategoryStore: function() {
        return new Ext.data.Store({
            autoLoad: true,
            fields: ['id', 'name'],
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'rs/question/getAllCategories',
                reader: {
                    type: 'xml',
                    record: 'Category'
                }
            }
        });
    },

    buildItems: function() {
        return [{
            xtype: 'combo',
            anchor: '100%',
            fieldLabel: 'Category',
            store: this.buildCategoryStore(),
            name: 'category',
            mode: 'local',
            multiSelect: false,
            valueField: 'id',
            displayField: 'name'
        }];
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks. first part is fixed. but for second one, it still didn't show option values in the drop down.

Comment: You're also missing displayField/valueField.

Comment: yes, it works now. you are a super man. Extjs is very hard for me to debug. how did you find out this error ?